# How to get the Current Date in Elastic Search Query?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I need to get the current date from the elastic search and get the weekoftheday from current date.

I came up with the below approach, but not able to figure out how to get that CURRENT DATE

```json
{
  "_source": "false",
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['record_created_at'].value.getWeekOfWeekyear() == <CURRENT DATE>.getWeekOfWeekyear()"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Current Week Demos": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "_id"
      }
    }
  },
}
```

**Note:** `now` method working fine with `aggs` but not in `query`

Any ideas to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can try to use [scripted fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-fields.html#script-fields) from elasticsearch

```
GET your_index/_search

{
"script_fields": {
"week_of_year": {
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); cal.setTime(new Date()); cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);"
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: But the mentioned obj doesn't have any method similar to `getWeekOfWeekyear` ?

Comment: @DilLip_Chowdary Updated example query in answer. Hope this meets your requirements)